# Completely restart Linux (modules, usb, pci, thunderbolt) without reboot

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, systemd, usb

Currently, I see the weekly issue that Linux doesn't wake from sleep nor does it wake properly from TB3 and USB-C docks, as well as undocking and docking. Majority of the problem is the kernel just needs to reload the  modules and remount the devices without losing the user session. (e.g not logging out and in again or losing gnome-shell)

I'd like to be able to do the *Without* rebooting the system, as one wants to maintain gnome-session and tmux sessions, but drastically restart services e.g NetworkManager
I know this is somewhat possible with modprode but I'd like to understand if there is a greater solution or some ugly scripts people have used to gain the same effect.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to restart GNOME (as suggested in your title) or not (as indicated in your question)?

Comment: Yes true, currently i do that by running `killall -3 gnome-shell` as it cleans up nicely without restarting apps and losing the users session

Comment: OK, and does that also clean up your suspend problems?

Comment: I have never done this, but you should be able to define a custom runlevel with only those services running that you want and provide transistion scripts to unload/load the kernel modules

Comment: @StephenKitt it doesn't solve the suspend problems, but as we've seen in the last 10yrs of linux on laptops, it's never solved, hence why I look for a ugly hacky solution just cycle the issues that do create this problem